# import an xml file generated by Excel in Python

Tags: python-2.7, minidom

I have an xml file generated by an excel software. The file is done this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 ...
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Table1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="9" ss:ExpandedRowCount="162" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="110.25" ss:Span="8"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Sezione</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Bambino</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Sesso</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Luogo di nascita</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Data di nascita</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Indirizzo</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CAP</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Città</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Accompagnatori</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ARANCIONE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">pippo </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Maschile</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Mirano (VE)</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">2000-02-08</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Via xx, 10</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">00000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xxx</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">xxx mmm</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 ...
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I need to read the python xml file to process the cell contents.
I use the minidom, but I can not properly import the content of the cells, broken down by rows.

I wrote this code, but I can not extract the string:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("xxx.xml")
itemlist=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Row')

for s in itemlist :
    item=s.getElementsByTagName('Cell')
    print item
```

Does anyone know how to help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("D:\xxx.xml")

itemlist=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Row')
bambino=0
for rows in itemlist :
    item=rows.getElementsByTagName('Cell')
    for Celle in item:
        for child in Celle.childNodes:
            print child.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

I hope this can be useful to someone.

Comment: This can't even able parse xml spreadsheet!

    xmldoc = minidom.parse("test.xml")
  File "C:\Python38\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1959, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 911, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 114, column 75